# Prevent multiple login using the same user name and password

Tags: java, servlets

I am developing an application that needs to prevent multiple login using the same user name and password.

If it happens on the same machine then obviously we need to do something with the user session, but it should also prevent if they are login on different machines using the same user name and password.

We have to keep following things in mind:

1. If user close the browser without logout.
2. If session time out.

I would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: Do you have some kind of central storage system that you are using for tracking user/session data? If so what is it.

Comment: Are you using Spring security framework? Or you have implemented your own. Is this question closed?

Answer (score 26):

> *If user close the browser without logout.*

Particularly this case is hard and not reliable to detect. You could use the `beforeunload` event in Javascript, but you're fully dependent on whether the browser has JS enabled and the particular browser supports this non-standard event (e.g. Opera doesn't). That's also one of the major reasons that I'd suggest to just logout the previously logged in user instead of preventing the login. That's also more user-friendly and secure for the case that the user "forgot" to logout from the other computer.

Easiest way is to let the `User` have a `static Map<User, HttpSession>` variable and let it implement [`HttpSessionBindingListener`](http://java.sun.com/products/servlet/2.2/javadoc/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionBindingListener.html) (and [`Object#equals()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) and [`Object#hashCode()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29)).

```
public class User implements HttpSessionBindingListener {

    // All logins.
    private static Map<User, HttpSession> logins = new HashMap<User, HttpSession>();

    // Normal properties.
    private Long id;
    private String username;
    // Etc.. Of course with public getters+setters.

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        return (other instanceof User) && (id != null) ? id.equals(((User) other).id) : (other == this);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return (id != null) ? (this.getClass().hashCode() + id.hashCode()) : super.hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        HttpSession session = logins.remove(this);
        if (session != null) {
            session.invalidate();
        }
        logins.put(this, event.getSession());
    }

    @Override
    public void valueUnbound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
        logins.remove(this);
    }

}
```

When you login the `User` as follows:

```
User user = userDAO.find(username, password);
if (user != null) {
    request.getSession.setAttribute("user", user);
} else {
    // Show error.
}
```

then it will invoke the `valueBound()` which will remove any previously logged in user from the `logins` map and invalidate the session.

When you logout the `User` as follows:

```
request.getSession().removeAttribute("user");
```

or when the session is timed out, then the `valueUnbound()` will be invoked which removes the user from the `logins` map.

Comment: +1 imho, this is trickiest use case. makes sense to log out the previous user, else you will have to wait till the sessions times out before you can log in again.

Comment: I agree - many users will close a tab / window rather than clicking a logout button, and waiting for the session to time out would be really annoying.

Comment: I am reading this and I am confused about the Map of users. Is the user class ApplicationScoped? As well is request an instance of HttpRequest?

Answer (score 6):

Create one table in your database — let's call it `[online_users]` — with three fields:

```
[online_users]
1. username
2. login_time
3. logout_time
```

Whenever a user logs in, insert the user's name and the login time into `[online_users]`.

On all pages which require users to log in, place this condition: check `[online_users]` to see if the user's `logout_time` is blank or not.

Whenever a user presses a logout button, set the `logout_time` in `[online_users]` for that user's name.

If someone tries to log in with an active username and password, check for `username` and `logout_time` and display a message stating that the user is already logged in. **And, most importantly, set `logout_time` to `MULTIPLELOGIN` for that user.**

If that user is logged in on any other machine, then if he refreshes or navigates to another page the site will tell him that he has been logged out. Then, the user can be redirected to the homepage of the site.

Answer (score 3):

Take one extra field in table with the column name say "IsLoggedIn" as bit field and set it to true until the user is logged in. As soon as user logs out set it to false.
This need to be done for session expiry time also.
As soon as the session expires this field should be set to false automatically using triggers or thru SP call

good solution is still welcome

Comment: Mr. Shantanu Gupta,
This seems to be achievable. But before implemeting I would like to know how to get an event that will provide that session has expired. 
Help.

Comment: under server configuration u need to set session expiry time, as soon as your session xpires which is stored under database u can set IsLoggedIn variable to be false and reset session field. 

For web applications u usually dont need IsLoggedIn field as ur session field itself depicts that if Session Field is not Null then a user is already logged in but under window application there is no concept of session, so in that case u can use above mentioned method.

Comment: Go thru the link for more details on how to use session variable.
http://techpint.com/programming/how-create-session-variable-aspnet

Comment: what if the user closes the browser or tab without logging out? how do we handle such scenario?

Answer (score 2):

I would also advise for Shantanu Gupta's solution - have a database column indicating the the user is currently logged, and update that column accordingly.

In order to 'capture' session expiration, you need to define in your `web.xml`:

```
<listener>
   <listener-class>com.foo.MySessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Where `MySessionListener` is your implementation of the `HttpSessionListener` interface (provided by the Servlet API).

Answer (score 2):

I would simply suggest using a security framework to handle all these details for you.  [Spring Security](http://static.springsource.org/spring-security/site/), for example, is fairly easy to integrate into an existing project, can be customised quite heavily if needs be - and most importantly, **it has built-in support for detecting and controlling concurrent logins**.

Don't reinvent the wheel when it's not needed, else you'll end up spending a good bit of time to create a bumpy wheel.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe overly simplified, but hey... it works for me in Web2Py:

Only on successful login, I am writing the SessionID (response.session_id) in the auth_membership table. 
On the landing page (index page) I check whether the current response.session_id is equal to the SessionID coming from the DB.
If so  - all is fine.
If not - (the "older" , first) user is politely logged out.

The above works since with each login a NEW response.session_id is created and stored in the DB.
The checking is done only on the landing page (which in my app is the most important one, initiating many other functions), so not too many DB hits for the above.
The above is not dependent on the user logging out.
No IP address is involved (which others have mentioned, suffers from its own issues)
It allows only ONE user to be logged in at a time and it logs out the "older" user.

Hope it helps
NeoToren

Answer (score 0):

I'd track each user's last known IP address and a timestamp for when they were last on that IP. Then you can just block access from other IPs for 5 minutes, an hour, or whatever you like.

Whenever the IP address switches, you can a) expire the user's old session, so they're forced to log back in and b) increment a per-user counter (which you can zero out every hour). If the counter goes above 5 (or something), you can block all access to the user's account for a longer period of time.

Comment: Due to NAT and dynamic IP allocation, any solution that depends on IP addesses will cause problems and I would advise against it.

Comment: If your usual user's IP changes 5 times in an hour, well then yes. Go for something else.

Answer (score 0):

You could store some sort of session-id for the user when logging in. When the user logs out or when the session expires, you remove that information again.

When a user tries to log in, and you already have a session-id stored for this user, let the user confirm that, and then invalidate the old session.

A user will certainly want to login again immediately if the browser crashed or something like that, so letting the user wait for the session to expire might be annoying.

Does this make sense for your application?

Comment: Mr. Peter Lang,
I believe session-id can only be maintained at client side/browser end. What will happen if two users are sharing the same login details but sitting on different machines ?

Help.

Comment: Cant't you assign and return a session-id at the server on login? What is the reason for two users sharing the same login details?

Comment: We can take an extra field (LoggedIn) in database table and make it true or false when someone login or logout. How can we assign the session-id at server when some user will login. Please make me aware. Thanks in advance.

Comment: By using $Session['Id'] at aspx page u can retrieve the session id at the page, for that u need to create a session first. 
http://techpint.com/programming/how-create-session-variable-aspnet

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily enforced if you have session. For each browser login, you should create a session record in session DB. The session ID can be used as authentication cookie. The session DB also has an index with username. At login, you can query the database to check how many sessions are there. We actually allows one session for each type. For example, user can have a login from mobile phone and another one from browser. But it can't have 2 browser sessions.

To solve the problem you mentioned. You have 2 options,

1. Have a very short session timeout (like 5 minutes) and extend session on every use. This way, user will be automatically logged out if leaving without logging out.
2. Bump the other session. The new session bumps the old session. The bumped session stays in DB with a special flag for 24 hours. We display a message to tell user the other session is being bumped and displays time and IP. This way, user will get notified if their account is being compromised.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented a possible solution for myself,

in the loginFilter I use, I set a lastloggedin, userloggedin and userSession within the user record on my system.

```
            user.setUser_lastlogged(new Date());
            user.setUser_loggedin(true);
            user.setSessionId(request.getSession().getId());
            appService.saveUsers(user);
```

so when i go to any of my struts2 actions i have a snippet of code in the prepare method.

```
@Override
public void prepare() throws Exception {
    UsersBase usercheck = appservice.getUserByUsername((String)request.getSession().getAttribute("j_username"));
    if(request.getSession().getId().equals(usercheck.getSessionId())){
        request.getSession().invalidate();
    }

}
```

This will log the user out when they login on another machine, or if you don't want to log them in i could do the following on the loginFilter

```
 UsersBase userdto = appService.getUserByUsername(username);
        if (userdto != null) {
            if ((userdto.getUser_loggedin())) {
                if (request.getSession().getId().equals(userdto.getSessionId())) {
                    authRequest.eraseCredentials();
                    request.getSession().setAttribute("error", "You are already logged in ");
                } 
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the token

When user logins success, the server side returns a token string to client/browser side, and server side saves a map with userID - token.
The client repeatedly checks/requests to server with that token, if the token is not same, this user logs multiply times.

When logoff, it saves the token into cookies or file system in the client side, and brings this token when loging next time.

Table:

```
userid:token:log_date
```

Answer (score 0):

How to identify whether browser is still active or not?

> Make a dummy ajax call on every minute and record the status in
>   HttpSession against the User, session id and along with the time
>   of last call. When the same user logins with new session, check
>   against the user in HttpSession and check time if it exceeds more
>   than a minute, it means that the previous browser is closed/ not active.

**Note:** Time setting as per your requirement (in my case its 1 minute).

> Along with above condition check, add code mentioned in the comment **"If user close the browser without logout."**

```
public class User implements HttpSessionBindingListener
```