# Checking the user login

Tags: java, session, web-applications

I have typical requirement that, if a user login to application and if he tries to log from different machine, system should through an message "as user already loggedin" and not to log him again.

Please can anyone suggest in which way i can achieve this requirement.

Thanks.

Comment: and the system is what kind of application (web, desktop.. ?)?

Comment: If you're storing the user information in a DB, you can add a "loggedin" column to the user table.

Comment: but hiting DB and cross checking may cause performance issue. if application contains thousands of users

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Web Application :

- You can store logged in user's list in application scope [make sure its *synchronized*]
- As user try to log in check in map and prompt

Answer (score 3):

You can store list of logged users somewhere

Answer (score 1):

- You can have a login Flag associated with User object to verify if user is already logged or not.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you:

[prevent multiple login using the same user name and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932091/prevent-multiple-login-using-the-same-user-name-and-password)

look for the **BalusC**'s answer. It has some useful insights and code examples.