# lock logged in user in oracle by java

Tags: java, oracle, jsp, servlets, authentication

i have one java web application in jsp and servlet and db as oracle 10g EE. In login if one user has been logged in then how can i prevent same user from logging again unless sign out?

**Note:** I am **not** telling that if a logged in user will click on login page then immediately he would be forwarded to his home page.

I am asking is how can i prevent that logged in user to login again if he is already logged in. Suppose user A is already logged in into the db(sign out not done), then user B tries to login in to db with the user id and password of user A, then simply user B will be prevented from login. How do i implement that?

Answer (score 2):

You need to manage a map of logged in users, `Map<String, String> userToSessionIdMap` when user logs in you check if there is any session exist for this user name if yes deny else allow login,

Now on logout you need to remove the entry from map, also you need to implement `HttpSessionBindingListener` so when session expires it removes the entry again

**Also See**

- [prevent multiple login using the same user name and password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932091/prevent-multiple-login-using-the-same-user-name-and-password)
- [Preventing multiple login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5578045/checking-the-user-login)

Comment: ok but if a user does not click sign out and simply closes the browser then how can he be logged out from that session?

Comment: ok i have to manage a map of logged in users in db too? i am not getting that Map<String, String> userToSessionIdMap

Comment: where m i wrong [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9818100/trace-logout-time-using-httpsessionbindinglisteners/9818282#9818282)

Answer (score 2):

Let the database do it's own job!

(This solution assumes that you can get help from DBAs; or you have SYSDBA access to the database.)

First create a profile that allows only 1 session per user:

```
CREATE PROFILE single_session_profile
       LIMIT SESSIONS_PER_USER 1;
```

Then create the user with the right profile or alter an existing user to use the profile:

```
CREATE USER user_a
       IDENTIFIED BY user_id
       DEFAULT TABLESPACE users
       TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp
       QUOTA UNLIMITED ON users
       PROFILE single_session_profile;
```

or

```
ALTER  USER user_a
       PROFILE single_session_profile;
```

Finally, the database needs to be observe these limits:

```
ALTER  SYSTEM SET RESOURCE_LIMIT = TRUE SCOPE = MEMORY;
```

(`SCOPE = MEMORY` enables limit enforcement for the currently running database instance; if you want to make it persistent, i.e. enabled after a database restart, you need to use `SCOPE = BOTH` where `BOTH` means both `MEMORY` and `SPFILE`, i.e. DB initialization file. If the database does not use the new `SPFILE` format, but the old `PFILE` (`init.ora`), then you need to add the `RESOURCE_LIMIT` setting to the `init.ora` and restart the database.)

That's it. If a `user_a` tries to log in twice, it will get:

```
ORA-02391: exceeded simultaneous SESSIONS_PER_USER limit
```

Comment: yep good solution, if i will write above code in will it affect the dba administrator?