# Prevent users from login to same system using different browsers (IE and FF)

Tags: java, browser, servlets, jakarta-ee, httpsession

We have a web application where users can login.

Now what we want is that the same user should not be able to login using different browsers.

Basically currently a user using two different browsers (IE and FF) can log in to the same account at the same time.  When you hit the login button, is it possible to invalidate all other logins for that account.

What is the best possible approach to do this?

PS: We are using Struts, Spring and Hibernate in our web application.

Thanks !

Comment: Look at the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932091/prevent-multiple-login-using-the-same-user-name-and-password

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing this on server-side is your best bet. You can keep tract of logged-in users in your application context.

Well, a little hint. Make use of a Servlet Filter, say `AuthFilter`, and make validation, may be `isAlreadyLoggedIn()`, over there beside other validations like username/password etc.. Now after having this check in place, you either -- that it depends what you want to do with the user trying to log in, show the message that "user already logged-in", or you can let the user log-in and invalidate the previous session. As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932091/prevent-multiple-login-using-the-same-user-name-and-password).

Comment: There can be a possibility that a user has logged in on one browser and then closed the browser without doing proper logout. Here in this case how do we keep track if the user has not closed the other browser?

Comment: @Ashish It means user is not logged out technically.

Comment: @Ashish: session-timeout comes handy here. Assign it a lower value.

Comment: As a complement to Jigar's comment, .... and re-opening the browser and visiting the same URL within a certain duration might load the existing session.

Comment: @Adeel Ansari I have one more questions. If user logins on IE, his session is created. Now if he logins to FF I need to invalidate his session in IE and start a new session in FF. How can I do that?

Comment: Stating a new session in FF is not a problem but how do I invalidate the previous session in IE?

Comment: @Ashish: The answer is you don't and you don't care. As soon as you received a request from the user who is already logged-in, you just grab his previous session, invoke `invalidate()` on it, and hook the user to the new session created using `request.getSession()`.

Comment: Moreover, you might like to transfer all the data from the former session to the new one before invalidating the former. If there is a need.

Comment: You can have ajax polling mechanism to track active browser.

Comment: @Adeel Ansari If I keep so many logged in users in the application context, wont it become heavy? Are there any downsides of using application context?

Comment: @Ashish: Not really. You must also clear the user from `applicationContext` upon logout.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the logged in user information in database or you can get it from Application context. and if the user is logged in already don't allow to make him another session.

Answer (score 0):

**Google** uses some **ip address mechanism** to *logout the user logged in another computer,instead of logging off in the same browser or tab*.

May be we can use **[geoip database](http://www.maxmind.com/app/ip-location)** [**Geolitecity**](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity)  to save the ***user's ip + Balusc answer of storing session using user as the key and the ip address*** for the solution .

Have a column `isLoggedIn` in database. Set to **Y** , if it logged, if the same user log's in from the another computer or brower, invalidate the session. Mind to set it to **N** ,if session expires.

*** For  Best  Read the Balusc's answer ***

[prevent-multiple-login-using-the-same-user-name-and-password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932091/prevent-multiple-login-using-the-same-user-name-and-password)  using  `HttpSessionBindingListener`.

Comment: I don't recommend this DB approach here. It might be suitable in case there is no other way around. But I wouldn't consider it as a first option. But, yes it comes handy in case you need this data for reporting purpose in future. Disclaimer: No negative vote casted.

Comment: @Adeel: ok , what about application context destroyed during classloader reload . how about saving the logged in users in a file in server side.

Comment: I like this db approach but I wont be needing this data for any reports etc. I also don't want to make any DB changes here. I would rather go with Adeel's approach with bit of Balusc approach minus the db change. :-)

Comment: @Adeel,@Ashish : what about using geo ip,session and user for logging out user logged in another computer, instead on the same computer.

Comment: And how about changing the whole application to an iPhone application? But the question is, what is required by the product owner?