# single ip access jsp

Tags: jsp, servlets

how can i restrict only single ip access allowed to access using JSP? I try to figure out how to avoid multiple ip accesses with the same username whenever s/he logs in. Thanks in advance. Any snippet will be highly valued.

Comment: It's basically impossible: a user could be behind a proxy, access the application using 5 different machines, and you would only see a single IP. But what's the end goal? Why such a restriction?

Comment: @JBNizet: Well, currently i still can access with the same username from different ip. I want to make it like when i already logged in from a certain ip address, i can not access with the same user name from another ip address. Is it possible?

Comment: It's impossible to cover all the cases, as I already said in my previous comment. But you don't answer my question: what's the end goal? Why such a restriction? Why are you concerned about users using different IPs? Why does it matter?

Comment: You can save the address (e.g. in DB) and on request check if the current user is accessing it from the same address, otherwise give error message/redirect/etc.

Comment: @JBNizet: The End goal is to prevent a user when s/he forgot to logout. S/he can not log in from different ip address until s/he logs out first. Sure, it can be handled using session timeout but what if the time difference is very small. Anyway, i found this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932091/prevent-multiple-login-using-the-same-user-name-and-password. Will it be suitable for my case?

Comment: @AndrásKerekes:Could you please give some example snippets? Thanks

Comment: So that has nothing to do with IP. You just want to prevent a single user to open two concurrent sessions. I still don't see the point, but at least you don't need to mess with IPs. You will annoy your users with such a feature. Most users don't log out. They just close their browser. And once closed, it's impossible for them to log out. So they will have to wait for the timeout to be able to log in.

Comment: As I said, you shouldn't. If you really want to do it, then, at login, set a loggedIn flag to true for this user in the database. At the next login, check that this flag is false before proceeding. At logout, reset the flag to false.

Comment: @JBNizet: Ah, ok. I will try it. Thanks anyway. Sorry i just removed my previous comment since I read there's also a new comment from you.

Comment: There is definitely value in preventing concurrent sessions from the same user. One way of solving the issue with users not logging out when leaving is to simply invalidate any existing sessions when starting a new one.

Comment: Keeping track of the IP from which the session was initiated is also useful for detecting session hijacking (if a session is suddenly used from a different IP the session has likely been hijacked and should be terminated). Like @JBNizet says it's probably necessary to allow multiple users from the same IP however (due to NAT routers and similar).