# How to prevent multiple login with same credentials on different devices in java

Tags: java, session, servlets

I have an requirement that : I need to prevent multiple logins with same credentials on different devices,i.e.Logout the previous login user and allow the new user for login.

Lets say `user_A` is already login then `user_B` tries to login to the application with the same credentials of `user_A` then logout the `user_A` and allow the `user_B` to login.I tried this with `servlet` and `session` but unable to resolve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Store a value in a session variable.  Check this variable before allowing access to a login page.

Comment: If both users use the same credentials, they are the same user. So what you mean is: prevent multiple login for a user.

Comment: Ah, do you mean from two different browsers?  If so you need to keep the information on the server.  Also catch session timeouts

Comment: possible duplicate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1932091/prevent-multiple-login-using-the-same-user-name-and-password?lq=1

Comment: No.i have seen that question but not same as my requirement as i want to allow new user to login and logout the previous login user.i used session timeout when user closes the browser or in case of crash server in my application.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a concept of application scope.

When a user logs in, simply register him as logged in in this application scope context (For example if you were using jsf/cdi you would store this in an `@ApplicationScoped` or `@Singleton` bean)

This example assumes you are defining your own context.

```
//Application scoped.
//You need also more or less make it singleton
public enum MyApplication{
  CURRENT_APPLICATION;

  public void onLogin(MyUser user, HttpSession session){}
  public MyUser getCurrentUser(HttpSession session) {}
  public boolean isLoggedIn(MyUser user){} //logged in on any session
  public boolean isLoggedIn(MyUser user, HttpSession session){} //logged in on this session
  public void logoutUser(MyUser user){} //logs out the user in any session
}

public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet{
  //somewher in do get or post
  private void login(String username, String password) {
    MyUser user = findUser(username, password);
    boolean loggedInAnotherSession = MyApplication.CURRENT_APPLICATION.isLoggedInUser(user);
    //logout the user from the other session or something like that
    boolean loggedInOnThisSession = MyApplication.CURRENT_APPLICATION.isLoggedInUser(user, getSession()); //session from http request
    //logout the user if the he is loggedin in a different session other than this
    if(!loggedInAnotherSession || !loggedInOnThisSession){
      //user is either logged in a different session or not logged in at all.
      //login the user
      MyApplication.CURRENT_APPLICATION.onLogin(user, getSession());
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your help but This will not help when user login from different machines

Comment: Are you running different application servers? If It is the same application under the same application server, why would it not help?

Comment: application server is same.but there will create two sessions for two logins then how will i compare two users?

Answer (score 1):

Not in Java and maybe overly simplified, but hey... it works for me in Web2Py:

Only on successful login, I am writing the SessionID (response.session_id) in the auth_membership table in the MySQL DB. 
On the landing page (index page) I check whether the current response.session_id is equal to the SessionID coming from the DB.
If so  - all is fine.
If not - (the "older" , first) user is politely logged out.

The above works since with each login a NEW response.session_id is created and stored in the DB.
The checking is done only on the landing page (which in my app is the most important one, initiating many other functions), so not too many DB hits for the above.
The above is not dependent on the user logging out.
No IP address is involved (which others have mentioned, suffers from its own issues)
It allows only ONE user to be logged in at a time and it logs out the "older" user.

Hope it helps
NeoToren

Answer (score 0):

You need to use session attributes and check if the attribute is empty or not. if the attribute is not empty replace it with your new user object.

```
User currentUser=(User)request.getSession().getAttribute("loggedUser");

if(currentUser!=null)
request.getSession().setAttribute("loggedUser",currentUser);

else
request.getSession(true).setAttribute("loggedUser",currentUser);
```